# MSG File format Parsing

Tags: c#, email, rtf, msg

Does anyone know how to get the attached linked images of a RTF email from c#?

I've tried a few component vendors and blogs from the internet but none of them support getting the linked images of a RTF email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by open the file using structured storage method.

After this you can loop though the attachment folders getting out the stream which are call "CONTENT"

I hope this help some if they ever need to do this

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue if they support it, but did you try Aspose.Email?

Comment: due to business reasons i cant use that vendor.